# vlookup between values of different length

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to do a VLookup() for the best match between two rows where the length of the values are different.

```
35799700000     1902718 X1  
35796961001     3584570 X2  
35796961001     3584573 X3  
35799700000     3584575 X4  
35795977777     3584576 X5  
351309312001    3579    X6  
35795977777     41      X7  
417999838729              
67572210124         
320301120086
```

for example the first number `35799700000` should bring me back `3579`

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? and have you already tried something you can show us in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some assumptions because you haven't been very descriptive in your question

The formula below resizes your lookup table values to be the same length as your lookup value. E.g. when comparing `35799700000`, the lookup value `41` will actually be `41000000000` in the lookup table. Once all lookup table values have been scaled up the closest number to your lookup value is calculated using `MIN()` and `ABS()`, and the corresponding `X1`,`X2`... etc returned (I assumed this from your setup above)

```
{=INDEX($E$1:$E$7,MATCH(MIN(ABS(($D$1:$D$7*(10^(LEN($A2)-LEN($D$1:$D$7))))-$A2)),ABS(($D$1:$D$7*(10^(LEN($A2)-LEN($D$1:$D$7))))-$A2),0))}
```

This is an array formula so leave out the curly braces and enter using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Image of working model below. If you don't use the same setup, you will need to change the cell references in the formula

[image]